# Hadoop Context type parameters in Kotlin

Tags: hadoop, kotlin

When implementing a Hadoop Mapper or Reducer in Kotlin, I get an interesting contradiction from the compiler. Any time you use the `Context` object, the compiler gives an error saying "4 type arguments expected" if you don't supply type arguments (`<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>`), and says "No type arguments expected" if you DO supply type arguments. Any ideas what's happening here?

An example:

```
// gives "4 type arguments expected"
override fun setup(context: Context?) {
    super.setup(context)
}

// gives "No type arguments expected"
override fun setup(context: Context<KeyIn, ValueIn, KeyOut, ValueOut>?) {
    super.setup(context)
}
```

Specifying `Mapper<KeyIn, ValueIn, KeyOut, ValueOut>.Context` makes it compile, but since `Context` is an inner class of `Mapper`, shouldn't the type of the `Context` be implied when you specify the type of the `Mapper` you're extending, as it is in Java?

Comment: For those interested, it appears Kotlin doesn't capture any generics in inner classes. I made a ticket on the YouTrack that has been assigned: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11123 and there's a parent ticket for the generics in inner classes issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin is expecting "4 type arguments" on `Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>` and not on the `Context` in `Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>.Context`.

An example:

```
override fun setup(context: Mappert<KeyIn, ValueIn, KeyOut, ValueOut>.Context?) {
    super.setup(context)
}
```

It is possible that the type arguments for `Context` should/could be implied. I suggest creating an issue in the [Kotlin YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).