# Inner classes Inheritance in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create a hierarchy of few classes, each one overriding some behavior in inner classes of it's parent (Specifically iterators, but it does not matter). Basically, it looks like this:

```
open class SuperClass<T>{
    protected open inner class InnerClass{
        fun someLogic(){
            println("some logic happened")
        }

        open fun someOverridableLogic(){
            println("some logic happened")
        }
    }
}

class ChildClass<T> : SuperClass<T>(){
    protected inner class ChildInnerClass:InnerClass{
        override fun someOverridableLogic(){
            super.someOverridableLogic()
            println("some OTHER logic happened")
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler refuses to work with this code, expecting type parameter on InnerClass when ChildInnerClass inherits from it. However, after adding parameter like this:

```
protected inner class ChildInnerClass:InnerClass<T>
```

compiler suddenly does **not** expect any type parameters!

Java equivalent of this compiles and executes as expected, without type parameters:

```
public class SuperClass<T> {
    protected class InnerClass{
        public void someLogic(){
            System.out.println("some logic happened");
        }

        public void someOverridableLogic(){
            System.out.println("some logic happened");
        }
    }
}


public class ChildClass<T> extends SuperClass<T>{
    protected class ChildInnerClass extends InnerClass{
        @Override
        public void someOverridableLogic() {
            super.someOverridableLogic();
            System.out.println("some OTHER logic happened");
        }
    }
}
```

So, am i doing something wrong in Kotlin, or is it simply a language restriction i wasn't aware about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is not expecting a type argument on `InnerClass` but on `SuperClass` in `SuperClass.InnerClass`. This is a known issue: [Capture generics in inner classes : KT-9208](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-9208).

For now you can do the following:

```
open class SuperClass<T> {
    protected open inner class InnerClass {
        fun someLogic() {
            println("some logic happened")
        }

        open fun someOverridableLogic() {
            println("some logic happened")
        }
    }
}

class ChildClass<T> : SuperClass<T>() {
    protected inner class ChildInnerClass : SuperClass<T>.InnerClass() {
        override fun someOverridableLogic() {
            super.someOverridableLogic()
            println("some OTHER logic happened")
        }
    }
}
```

See also [Hadoop Context type parameters in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35491648/3255152) for a similar example and answer.

Comment: Piggybacking a question as I'm new to Kotlin: I'm trying to get my head around this and the code on the answer doesn't compile for me. I had to add the type parameter on `InnerClass` too, so it ended up being `inner class ChildInnerClass : SuperClass<T>.InnerClass<T>()` which I think is what the linked answer suggests to do... am I missing something?

Comment: You need to specify type parameter on `InnerClass` only if you defined it with a type parameter (`protected open inner class InnerClass<T>`) In this code `InnerClass` does not require type parameters and instead uses T from it's parent, `SuperClass`

Comment: @Augusto if the code on the answer doesn't compile for you then I am guessing you made some changes to `InnerClass`, etc. As such, for clarity, I've updated the code in the answer to include the `SuperClass` declaration. You should be able to copy and paste the example into a new Kotlin file and it should compile without any problems. Please let us know if it doesn't for you.

Comment: Silly me! I added `<T>` to `SuperClass.InnerClass` at some point while playing with the code. Thanks for clarifying this!!!